# How do I write a variable a certain amount of times?

Tags: javascript, repeat

```
var x=5
var char="Hi!
```

Is there any way to make JS write char x amount of times inside of an html element?

```
<span>Hyper guy wants to tell you 
<script>
var x=5;
var char="Hi!;
document.write(char) and repeat x times;
</script>
</span>
```

The problem with using `document.write` is that it erases the whole page, so how would I insert it in context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop that loops 5 times, each time adding 'Hi!' onto the end.

```
var x = 5;
var char = '';
while (x--) {
    char += 'Hi!';
}
// write once
document.write(char);
```

Or, you *can* just write 5 times:

```
var x = 5;
var char = 'Hi!';
while (x--) {
    document.write(char);
}
```

Up to you which you choose, though I'd prefer the first (the less you mess with the document, the better).

Comment: I prefer `while(x--)` in cases like this

Comment: @Gabi, thanks that's much cleaner. I'll update my answer with this if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<span>Hyper guy wants to tell you 
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=5;
var c="Hi!"; //close the quotes.
for (;x>=0;--x)
    document.write(c);
</script>
</span>
```

`document.write(..)` doesnt erase the content of the *entire* page, if it is used in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Really? I'm not sure where you got the idea that it erases the page first.

When I execute the following in FF3, after adding the missing closing quote following `Hi!`:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span>
            Hyper guy wants to tell you
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var x=5;
                var chars="Hi! ";
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < x; i++) document.write(chars);
            </script>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get:

```
Hyper guy wants to tell you Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi! Hi!
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a HTML element in the page where you want to insert text

Use document.getElementById to get the element and append the text to element using .innerHTML .text property to it

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

example:

```
//add this empty span in the HTML page
<span id="newText"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x=5, count;
var char='Hi!', resultString = '';
for(count=0;count<x;count++)
{
resultString = resultString + char;
}
document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = resultString;
</script>
```